# Svg icon shows when viewed locally but doesn't show when deployed

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

I have a weird issue. I a musing a sprite for all my SVGs. They all work just fine, and even the one in issue works fine when I run my code locally.
But when I deploy it (firebase), one of the SVGs just doesn't show up. What could be the reason?

Here's the code for two of the SVGs. `smile` is the one that gives me issues, the other one doesn't.

```
<symbol id="create" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<title>create</title>
<path d="M11 6.999c2.395.731 4.27 2.607 4.999 5.001.733-2.395 2.608-4.269 5.001-5-2.393-.731-4.268-2.605-5.001-5-.729 2.394-2.604 4.268-4.999 4.999zm7 7c1.437.438 2.562 1.564 2.999 3.001.44-1.437 1.565-2.562 3.001-3-1.436-.439-2.561-1.563-3.001-3-.437 1.436-1.562 2.561-2.999 2.999zm-6 5.501c1.198.365 2.135 1.303 2.499 2.5.366-1.198 1.304-2.135 2.501-2.5-1.197-.366-2.134-1.302-2.501-2.5-.364 1.197-1.301 2.134-2.499 2.5zm-6.001-12.5c-.875 2.873-3.128 5.125-5.999 6.001 2.876.88 5.124 3.128 6.004 6.004.875-2.874 3.128-5.124 5.996-6.004-2.868-.874-5.121-3.127-6.001-6.001z"/>
</symbol>


<symbol id="smile" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<title>smile</title>
<path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 14h-12c.331 1.465 2.827 4 6.001 4 3.134 0 5.666-2.521 5.999-4zm0-3.998l-.755.506s-.503-.948-1.746-.948c-1.207 0-1.745.948-1.745.948l-.754-.506c.281-.748 1.205-2.002 2.499-2.002 1.295 0 2.218 1.254 2.501 2.002zm-7 0l-.755.506s-.503-.948-1.746-.948c-1.207 0-1.745.948-1.745.948l-.754-.506c.281-.748 1.205-2.002 2.499-2.002 1.295 0 2.218 1.254 2.501 2.002z"/>
</symbol>
```

They are both wrapped between these two together with all the other symbols

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
.....svgs......
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: are you using the id `smile` anywhere else in your page?

Comment: @ruskin no. I ended up changing the path to a different svg. My problem is solved but I'm still confused why this original one didn't work. Ended up compromising for an svg I wanted less.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by changing the `<symbol>` tag to one of `<svg>`.

I'm looking through the W3C documentation but I can't find the `<symbol>` tag, probably you or "firebase" are using some API or something to adjust the code, try something like this:

```html
<svg id="smile" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 <title>smile</title>
 <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 14h-12c.331 1.465 2.827 4 6.001 4 3.134 0 5.666-2.521 5.999-4zm0-3.998l-.755.506s-.503-.948-1.746-.948c-1.207 0-1.745.948-1.745.948l-.754-.506c.281-.748 1.205-2.002 2.499-2.002 1.295 0 2.218 1.254 2.501 2.002zm-7 0l-.755.506s-.503-.948-1.746-.948c-1.207 0-1.745.948-1.745.948l-.754-.506c.281-.748 1.205-2.002 2.499-2.002 1.295 0 2.218 1.254 2.501 2.002z"/>
 </svg>
```

You may be using an API that I think is also practical, which is the [fontAwesome API](https://fontawesome.com/), it is simple to move and fits well with the text.